# Koala with "sass-json-vars": CLI works, but GUI gets "Cannot load such file sass-json-vars"

Tags: json, sass, koala-app

I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Koala\ruby\lib\ruby\bin` added to the `PATH environment variable`.

When I install this gem with `gem install sass-json-vars`, it's installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Koala\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems`

When I run the command `sass core.scss core.css -r sass-json-vars --trace`, it works fine.

But if I open `koala-config.json` in my project-root and add `"customOptions": ["-r sass-json-vars"],`, each attempt by the GUI, or the GUI's 'watcher', to compile gives me the error **`"Cannot load such file -- sass-json-vars"`**.

If I remove the command, and the attempt to import json, the GUI works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was running the following command:

`gem install -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Koala\rubygems" sass-json-vars`, or similar syntax for any other gem if anyone should encounter this problem.